# df.sample(ignore_index=True) still returns index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**How do I `sample()` a row from a Dataframe, without its index?**

If there is a different approach, that's ok.

---

Pandas documentation offers `ignore_index` parameter.

> DataFrame.sample(n=None, frac=None, replace=False, weights=None,
> random_state=None, axis=None, ignore_index=False)

[Source](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)

However, when I run:

```py
df['col'].sample(ignore_index=True)
```

I'll still get the index and the value, e.g.:

```
1    value
```

Desired:

```
value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas all objects like `Series` and `DataFrame`s has index.

Parameter `ignore_index` obviously generate default RangeIndex, not remove it.

If need scalar from `Series` select first value:

```
out = df['col'].sample(1).iat[0]
```

Comment: TL;DR: **`.iat[0]`**